# ARM: stmia instruction much faster than ldmia?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm observing something that just can't be right.

I've found that I can write to main memory on the ARM using

```
 stmia r0!, {r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10}
```

about 6 times faster than I can read from main memory (SDRAM) using

```
 ldmia r0!, {r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10}
```

So literally if I replace ldmia with stmia and r0 points to an allocated piece of memory, the stmia is 6 times faster if I time it.

Is there something special about the ARM's stmia instruction that might be causing a false positive? Maybe stmia interacts strangely with the caches?

In general I have seen that the ARM can write faster than it can read from main memory, but 6 times faster makes no sense from a hardware perspective.

---

Update:
**This happens with large chunks of memory, bigger than the L2 cache probably is.**

Therefore the caching explanation does not make sufficient sense. Even if the ARM has a write-back L2 cache that takes forever to write back, it will not be larger than my allocated memory area is.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the alignment of these writes and reads and how are you timing them?  Are you timing the whole 20mb and then dividing by 20mb or are you trying to time each ldm/stm?  Ideally time the whole thing.  what arm platform are you running on?  processor core and bus?  writes are expected to be faster than reads, but over large amounts of data writes should only be slightly faster, a few percent at best not many times faster. random access writes can be hundreds of times faster depending on the system.

Comment: Alignment should always be 4 bytes. ARM platform is ipad2. I am doing sequential writes.

Comment: You did not answer if you're timing the whole transfer or not. Also, please post code on a pastebin, if possible.

Comment: if not aligned on a cache line boundary (bigger than 4 bytes) then you can incur an extra cache line read from ram for every ldm.  Not a 600 percent thing but it adds to it.  if reading linearly through memory then you only add one cache line for the whole range of memory which would be almost unnoticed.

Comment: I assume if the data cache is involved then you are using the mmu?  Like Igor said.  turn off the cache.  also turn off the mmu.  use the same memory range, increment address by 8 words between each (use the ! on the instruction) store, write many and average.  Repeat with reads.  what kind of a timer are you using, are you using all assembler or some C code for example and have you verified the compiler has not changed the position of your time sampling, been there seen that.  is your mmu configured right so that the time sampling is not cached?

Comment: have you verified that the timer is not rolling over/aliasing?

Comment: Alignment should be 8-bytes for LDM/STM, but it will work on 4-byte, just slower. Probably not 6-times slower, but please make sure it is the same between each test.

Comment: You can use `{r3-r10}` instead of `{r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10}`.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify your platform and environment, but I suspect you're seeing the effects of caching. When executing a load, first the cache is checked, and if the data is not there (cache miss), the CPU has to wait until it's actually fetched from the main memory, which is quite a bit slower than cache. The store, on the other hand, can just dump the data into cache and move on, counting on the cache controller to do the actual memory write without CPU's involvement.

To determine if it's the case, you can try various test patterns, e.g.:

1. Disable caching, this should make the timing reflect the actual memory access times.
2. Execute a load from the same address several times in a row. Repeated loads should be faster since they'll be hitting the cache.
3. Execute a load right after the store to the same address - this should use the value from the cache and be faster.
4. Flush the cache before each operation to reduce its influence on timings
5. Add a DSB after the store to make sure the actual write is completed before execution proceeds.

and so on. To read more about caching in ARM processors, I'd recommend reading the [Cortex-A Series Programmer's Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013a/index.html). It will be useful even if your processor is not a Cortex-A, as most concepts apply to older generations as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this happens with very large chunks of memory e.g. 20 MB. So it is larger than the L2 cache.

Comment: FWIW, I tried using DSB and flushing the data cache and there's very little change. Writes seem to be extremely fast i.e. they are not really going to main memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code:

```
.globl _start
_start:


    ldr r11,=0xD6800600
    mov r1,#0
    str r1,[r11,#0x08] ;@ stop timer
    mvn r1,#0
    str r1,[r11,#0x00] ;@ timer load register
    mov r1,#3
    str r1,[r11,#0x08] ;@ start timer, 1 x prescaler

    mov r3,#3
    mov r4,#4
    mov r5,#5
    mov r6,#6
    mov r7,#7
    mov r8,#8
    mov r9,#9
    mov r10,#10

    ldr r0,=0xD6001000
    mov r12,#0x400

    ldr r13,[r11,#0x04]
write_loop:
    stmia r0!, {r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10}
    subs r12,#1
    bne write_loop
    ldr r1,[r11,#0x04]

    ldr r0,=0xD6001000
    mov r12,#0x400

    ldr r2,[r11,#0x04]
read_loop:
    ldmia r0!, {r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10}
    subs r12,#1
    bne read_loop
    ldr r14,[r11,#0x04]

    mov r0,r13
    mov r3,r14

    ldr sp,=0xD600E000
    bl notmain
hang: b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
```

The peripheral base is 0xD6800000.  Using the on-core timer.  This is an mpcore r2p0 (rev 2.0) with a 64 bit AXI bus.  You may find it interesting that the writes are 3 times slower than the reads. printing out the times and subtracting writes are 0x191F5 ticks and reads 0x81F7.

But I know the reason why.  This memory controller can/does turn the stm into 4 double word write cycles (what you see on the AXI bus).  I think the read is a single  8 word (4 double word) transfer, so there is 4 times the bus overhead for the writes.  Overhead plus one clock for each write, each read is overhead plus 8 clocks to burst the data in.

I added code to verify the caches were turned off.  And added nops, one nop at a time to adjust the alignment of the instructions in memory (can still affect fetches, and implementation of the on chip memory).  Place the nops just before the read of the timer before each loop for example.  By manipulating the location of the loops in memory the read loop was most sensitive, I could change the results by 50% either way.  Instead of the 0x8xxx range it would go to 0xAxxx at one sensitive spot and 0x6xxx clocks at another.  I am not going to dig much into this, there are probably some effects from the ram itself, as well as affects from being an ARM11 with some smoothing from fetching as well as perhaps the unaligned reads being smoothed out into fewer aligned reads, etc.

I recommend you do the same, turn off the caches, turn off the mmu, turn off parity or ecc generation/checking.  Tighten the loops, time outside the loop.  Place nops one at a time out in front of the test code, one at a time possibly as many as 8 or 16 or 32, if there are variations the pattern should repeat on some logical boundary like 4, 8 or 16 words.  Also if your timer gives you a different number (without recompiling) run after run, you have interrupts or something like that going on which is going to mess up your numbers.  A processor core clock like this one I cant imagine would change even by one clock, depends on your memory system of course.  Ummm, since you are doing 8 word instructions, try changing the starting address by 0, 4, 8, and 12.  Also try turning on the instruction cache (dont need the mmu for that).  I suspect you will also see the performance numbers jump around.

There are some other ARM's I can try...Not chips I have as much internal knowledge about though...

What family/core are you running?  Can you post your test code?  Is your test loop similar to what I was doing above?

Comment: With an ARM7TDMI in an LPC2148 using the same test method as above writes 0x1A06 counts on the timer, reads 0x1C06 counts on the timer, nops and adjusting the starting address did not change the time.  Writes are faster but not by the margin you are seeing.

Comment: Hi, I'm not in a position to turn off the mmu since it's got an OS running that is there to stay. But I am flushing the data cache like so:  mcr  p15, 0, r4, c7, c10, 4

Comment: An update: I increased the size of the block that I am writing to, which gets read before it is written, and oddly the stmia performance has dropped without any use of nop's. However I tried adding nops to my vmstia writer and it is still running very fast, almost 3 GB/s. On a desktop system that rate would be believable, but since the vldmia of main memory is super-slow at 358 MB/s, I remain skeptical.

Comment: The nops are to change the actual address in memory where the loop of test code resides.  The loop starting at address 0xxxx1FC is a big difference from 0xxxx200 for example as it probably straddles a cache line and depending on what cache is doing you can lose performance, adding a nop changes it to 0xxxx200 for example.  but it moves all the rest of the code in the binary by one, Some code that resided before or after the nop that has to branch to or read from now needs extra instructions because the reach is too far, etc. a single nop can create a lot of chaos, both good chaos and bad.

Comment: adding/changing any line of code anywhere will perform the same task of moving the whole rest of the binary around changing cache alignments with critical loops, and in cores with 64 bit memory interfaces can also have effects with or without a cache. Did you use the same memory address range for the stm and ldm? and at try the mmu with caching off for that range?  and/or disable caching all together?the mmu will cause extra memory cycles but they should be consistent between the stm and ldm, if the stm test loop and ldm test loop are in a different mmu controlled block that couldchangethings

Answer (score 0):

@dwelch 
I think you're making an interesting point about NOPs however it is already proven that the code can run very fast when reading--- so long as it is accessing the caches and not main memory. The rate there is about 5000MB/s. Whereas writing is at 6000MB/s. So the NOPs don't really explain why writing to main memory is so much faster than reading from main memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you observed is the effect of the ARM's write buffer. The write buffer sits between the CPU and the cache or RAM. It is designed to prevent the CPU from waiting for the memory when doing small sets of writes. The typical write buffer can handle 4 unique addresses with 2 words each which would hold the registers you wrote in your example above. If you create a loop of stmia with 8 registers, you will start to see the true speed at which it can write. There is no coalescing of addresses, so if you write 4 bytes, that will fill the write buffer as well.